# nodejs url.parse test returns undefined

Tags: node.js, url

This might be a very stupid question, but is there a reason why `url.parse` would return `undefined` in this case, if I were to simply pass in a URL string, like so `proto.getProtocol("http://www.some.com/test")`?

Please bare in mind I am a novice with `nodejs`.

```
'use strict';

var url = require("url");

var proto = {};

proto.getProtocol = function (path) {
    console.log(path);
    var parts = url.parse(path, true);
    console.log(parts);
    return parts;
};

module.exports = proto;
```

`console.log(parts);` returns undefined as is, when I run the tests.

Test:

```
var chai = require('chai');
var sinonChai = require("sinon-chai");
var expect = chai.expect;
var extend = require('lodash').extend;
var sinon = require('sinon');
chai.use(sinonChai);
var proxyquire = require('proxyquire');

describe("getProtocol", function () {
    var testedModule, parseSpy, path;


    before(function () {

        path = "http://www.some.com/test";

        parseSpy = sinon.spy();

        testedModule = proxyquire('../getProtocol.js', {
            'url': {
                'parse': parseSpy
            }
        });

        testedModule.getProtocol(path);
    });

    it("calls url.parse", function () {
        expect(parseSpy).has.been.calledOnce.and.calledWithExactly(path, true);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `proxyquire` to replace `getProtocol`'s `url.parse` method with a function that does not do URL parsing (i.e., a Sinon spy function, produced by `sinon.spy()`). The spy function can tell you if it has been called, but it knows nothing about parings URLs.

You probably meant to do `sinon.spy(require("url"), "parse")`, which produces a spy function that calls `require("url").parse` and returns the result. By contrast, the function returned by `sinon.spy()` does nothing, except remember how it has been called.

Answer (score 1):

The code works fine.

```
var proto = require( './proto' );

var parts = proto.getProtocol( "http://www.some.com/test" );
console.log( parts );

{ protocol: 'http:',
  slashes: true,
  auth: null,
  host: 'www.some.com',
  port: null,
  hostname: 'www.some.com',
  hash: null,
  search: '',
  query: {},
  pathname: '/test',
  path: '/test',
  href: 'http://www.some.com/test' }
```

Can you post the entire code that you are using?

Comment: so far that's it. maybe there is something wrong with my test set-up then. I'll update with tests.